# Event Delegation in AngularJS (jQuery .on() replacement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, delegation

We are trying to remove jQuery as a dependency from one of our projects written in AngularJS, but we are having trouble when replacing this kind of constructions:

```
angular.element(ancestorSelector).on(eventType, descendantSelector, function() { 
  ... 
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

The main problem is that jqLite implements a simplified version of `.on()` which doesn't support this behavior. Also, some of the elements we are targeting in this scenario are out of the application scope, so we cannot bind events in link time.

What would be the best way to replicate this functionality in AngularJS or plain JS?

Our current approach is binding the event to the ancestor and then checking if the event target matches the descendant selector. We assume this is not the best solution to this problem, but we cannot figure out a cleverer way.

Comment: What do you think jQuery does under the hood?

Comment: @epascarello We actually had a look at the code, but their implementation seemed a little more complex than this.

Comment: What's the context that you will use this event delegation?